# Using the Android KeyStore in Robolectric tests

Tags: java, android, robolectric, android-keystore

I'm attempting to write a few testcases that work against the [Android Keystore](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.html). However, when I write the following test case:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, sdk = 21)
public class FancyPantsUnitTest {
   @Test
   public void buildKey() {
        keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "AndroidKeyStore");
        keyPairGenerator.initialize(4096);
        final KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
   }
}
```

This fails with the following exception:

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<null> but was:<java.security.KeyStoreException: AndroidKeyStore not found>
```

I'm targeting API Level **23** if that helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is already a discussion on this at https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/1518 .

In short:

> From java.security.Security javadoc:
>
> > The default values of security properties are read from an
> >     implementation-specific location, which is typically the properties
> >     file lib/security/java.security in the Java installation directory.
>
> … which we probably don't want to encourage people to monkey with.
>
> Looks like this will need to be a method intercept rule...

The same happens when trying PowerMockito.

Comment: I still don't get it. Is there a way to use both Robolectric and KeyStore?

Comment: For anyone else coming here. This article worked for me to test EncryptedSharedPreferences. https://proandroiddev.com/testing-jetpack-security-with-robolectric-9f9cf2aa4f61

Answer (score 3):

Matthew Dolan came up with an outstanding solution in his [article](https://proandroiddev.com/testing-jetpack-security-with-robolectric-9f9cf2aa4f61).

Here is the code to create a `FakeAndroidKeyStore`

```
import java.io.InputStream
import java.io.OutputStream
import java.security.Key
import java.security.KeyStore
import java.security.KeyStoreSpi
import java.security.Provider
import java.security.SecureRandom
import java.security.Security
import java.security.cert.Certificate
import java.security.spec.AlgorithmParameterSpec
import java.util.Date
import java.util.Enumeration
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator
import javax.crypto.KeyGeneratorSpi
import javax.crypto.SecretKey

object FakeAndroidKeyStore {

    val setup by lazy {
        Security.addProvider(object : Provider("AndroidKeyStore", 1.0, "") {
            init {
                put("KeyStore.AndroidKeyStore", FakeKeyStore::class.java.name)
                put("KeyGenerator.AES", FakeAesKeyGenerator::class.java.name)
            }
        })
    }

    @Suppress("unused")
    class FakeKeyStore : KeyStoreSpi() {
        private val wrapped = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType())

        override fun engineIsKeyEntry(alias: String?): Boolean = wrapped.isKeyEntry(alias)
        override fun engineIsCertificateEntry(alias: String?): Boolean = wrapped.isCertificateEntry(alias)
        override fun engineGetCertificate(alias: String?): Certificate = wrapped.getCertificate(alias)
        override fun engineGetCreationDate(alias: String?): Date = wrapped.getCreationDate(alias)
        override fun engineDeleteEntry(alias: String?) = wrapped.deleteEntry(alias)
        override fun engineSetKeyEntry(alias: String?, key: Key?, password: CharArray?, chain: Array<out Certificate>?) =
            wrapped.setKeyEntry(alias, key, password, chain)

        override fun engineSetKeyEntry(alias: String?, key: ByteArray?, chain: Array<out Certificate>?) = wrapped.setKeyEntry(alias, key, chain)
        override fun engineStore(stream: OutputStream?, password: CharArray?) = wrapped.store(stream, password)
        override fun engineSize(): Int = wrapped.size()
        override fun engineAliases(): Enumeration<String> = wrapped.aliases()
        override fun engineContainsAlias(alias: String?): Boolean = wrapped.containsAlias(alias)
        override fun engineLoad(stream: InputStream?, password: CharArray?) = wrapped.load(stream, password)
        override fun engineGetCertificateChain(alias: String?): Array<Certificate> = wrapped.getCertificateChain(alias)
        override fun engineSetCertificateEntry(alias: String?, cert: Certificate?) = wrapped.setCertificateEntry(alias, cert)
        override fun engineGetCertificateAlias(cert: Certificate?): String = wrapped.getCertificateAlias(cert)
        override fun engineGetKey(alias: String?, password: CharArray?): Key = wrapped.getKey(alias, password)
    }

    @Suppress("unused")
    class FakeAesKeyGenerator : KeyGeneratorSpi() {
        private val wrapped = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES")

        override fun engineInit(random: SecureRandom?) = Unit
        override fun engineInit(params: AlgorithmParameterSpec?, random: SecureRandom?) = Unit
        override fun engineInit(keysize: Int, random: SecureRandom?) = Unit
        override fun engineGenerateKey(): SecretKey = wrapped.generateKey()
    }
}
```

Use just before where the `java.security.KeyStore` gets called.

In example:

```
@Before
fun setup() {
  FakeAndroidKeyStore.setup
  KeyStore.getInstance(...)
  ...
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if it is the correct way. But worked for me for java unit test, I called `@Before public void setup() { FakeAndroidKeyStore.INSTANCE.getSetup(); }`