# Robolectric gives java.security.KeyStoreException: AndroidKeyStore not found

Tags: java, android, keystore, robolectric

So I wrote my application where I am using `KeyStore` to encrypt/decrypt data.
I also wrote a nice Robolectric test for it, but when I am trying to run the test I got the following exception:

```
java.security.KeyStoreException: AndroidKeyStore not found
```

for the following code:

```
keyStoreInstance = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
```

Any solution for this?

All I found was this:
https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/1518

Answer (score 0):

So, the reason behind this is AndroidKeyStore implementation is not there, when you running via Robolectric. 
[Using the Android KeyStore in Robolectric tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38213748/using-the-android-keystore-in-robolectric-tests)

You can avoid this exception by using the following:

```
isTestRunner(){
    return Build.FINGERPRINT.equalsIgnoreCase("robolectric");
}
```

If you have a class lets says **YourKeystore.class** which injected into many other classes you can still mock out your YourKeystore.class, which makes you able to test other classes.
If you would like to test the YourKeystore.class itself, I am afraid that isn't possible (see link above).

Comment: Adding it where?